# How to push new view controller in didReceiveRemoteNotification so that previous view controller doesnt show for a moment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification

I receive a pust notification and push a view controller based on the data i get in push.
I do it like this:

```
   UINavigationController *navVc=(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
   PictureTakeVC *pvc=[[PictureTakeVC alloc] init];
   [navVc pushViewController:pvc animated:NO];
```

It works, but the view controller that was opened before i pressed home button shows for a moment.

I also tried this but it happens the same:

```
PictureTakeVC *pvc=[[PictureTakeVC alloc] init];            
NSArray *vcs=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: pvc, nil];
UINavigationController *navVc=(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
navVc.viewControllers=vcs;
self.window.rootViewController = navVc;
```

How to push vc didReceiveRemoteNotification so that it opens immediatly and no other vc is shown for a moment?

Comment: how about presentModalViewController of UIViewController?

Comment: need to push it because of my hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said "but the view controller that was opened before i pressed home button shows for a moment.",

The reason is not the code, but the iOS system. 
It captures screenshot of the screen when app goes in background. As [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> **Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the
>   background**. When an app transitions to the background, the system
>   takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents
>   briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before
>   returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should
>   hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information
>   that might be captured as part of the snapshot.

So, if snapshot is removed then it will directly show the new pushed view controller.
(not sure about apple guideline for snapshot)

**Update:**

One approach can be: 
Add a black colored background on the app screen when it goes in background(in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method). So, it will show black screen while coming back to application.{ They store it for showing launch image for already started application.}

**Where it helps?**

When we delete snapshots from 'Preference' directory of application sandbox(after application goes in background) and  come back to application it shows black for a while as it does not have any snapshot.

The outcome of our approach and removing snapshot are same.

Comment: I guess snapshot cant be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `PictureTakeVC` is a view controller just use this instead

```
 PictureTakeVC *pvc = [[PictureTakeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PictureTakeVC" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: @DixieFlatline These view controllers wouldn't happen to be in a tab bar would they? Like you are on the first tab you leave the app then when you return on a notification you want to go to the second tab

Answer (score 1):

Before your app goes into background mode remove the view that is there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing something? The `didReceiveRemoteNotification` fires when your application is active and running.

...but anyway if you want to achieve what you are asking you have to detect there is a pushnotification from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (or may be from `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`) and push viewcontroller on rootviewcontroller from one of these methods.

To detect whether there were remote notification:

```
NSString *params = [[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"View"];
if (params) 
{
    // push view
}
```

Use following methods to push view, you won't see any other vc when application gets activated. Let me know if any issues.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
```

I have done similar for push notification so let me know what are you trying to achieve exactly if I understood wrong.

Comment: I have problems for cases when user is in the app, and then presses home (app still runs) and then receives push notification. So i need solution for handling view controllers in didReceiveRemoteNotification and not in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (that was working all the time).

Comment: okay. You will need to set your required information including user info received from the server and flag that tells you that remote notification was received in didReceiveRemoteNotification. And check for the flag and put pushview controller code in the applicationWillEnterForeground....You should be good. The idea is if you don't want to see previous vc you have to do your things in applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationWillEnterForeground, i.e. before user see any visible contents. I hope that makes sense..

Comment: I mean applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationWillEnterForeground!

Comment: isn;t that any useful to you? Let me know where you stuck.

Comment: It doesnt help. Looks like snapshot is made by ios and cant be removed.